# Django application design: Perform a common set of queries for each request

Tags: database, django, architecture, structure

I'm fairly new to Django and web-app development, so perhaps my question is not very well thought out.

For a new website I'm working on, I'd like to perform a set of database queries for every incoming request. I'm wondering what the best way to structure this in code would be.

To be more specific, I'd like to display a greeting (such as "Hi John,") and the status of the user's shopping cart in the header section whenever applicable. I considered creating a get_header_details helper function and calling it from every view method, but there has to be a better way to do this. Thoughts?

Also, even though I'd like to display the greeting and shopping cart status on every page, maybe I don't need to query for it on every page request. Is there a good way to do this? This is a learning project, so I'm ok with adding things to my technology stack.

Answer (score 2):

For the shopping chart, [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/) and a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) coupled with [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) and preferably [caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) (e.g. Memcached) is the way to go.

Middleware allows you to do arbitrary actions before or after every view. A context processor allows you to insert variables into every template. The most common way to implement a shopping chart is the use of sessions, as you normally don't want to save the state of the shopping chart indefinitely by default (you can of course provide this option as a convenience feature).

As for the greeting message, use caching to prevent an extra (probably unneeded) query on every request.

Comment: Note that you'll need to ensure that you're using a `RequestContext` rather than just the default `Context` for the context processors to work correctly.  The simplest way to do this is to get into the habit of using the `render` shortcut to produce your responses, rather than the older `render_to_request`.

Answer (score 0):

Django has good [caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) support. [Template fragment caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching) might be useful in your instance.